# How to create new array inside the each parent array and copy values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I am stuck in one scenario where needs to add new array object called "timeSeriesData" and "units" inside the each parent array object and needs to copy values inside the "timeSeriesData" from parent object.

Please do help me on this, it would be really appreciated.

Input -

```
{
  "1": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 23.77
    }
  ],
  "nth": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    }
  ]
}
```

Expected Output -

```
    1: {
      timeSeriesData: [
        {
          date: 1638334800,
          value: 0,
        },
        {
          date: 1638334900,
          value: 0,
        } 
      ], units: '%'
    },
    2: {
      timeSeriesData: [
        {
          date: 1638334900,
          value: 19.71,
        },
        {
          date: 1638334800,
          value: 23.77,
        }
      ], units: '%'
    },
   nth: {
      timeSeriesData: [
        {
          date: 1638334900,
          value: 19.71,
        },
        {
          date: 1638334800,
          value: 19.71,
        }
      ], units: '%'
    }
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution will mutate the original object to have the shape and properties you are looking for. Basically it loops through each property using a [for...in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) and reassigns the value of the prop to an object which has the array as `timeSeriesData` and a new unit prop.

```js
for(let number in theObject){
  theObject[number] = {
    timeSeriesData: theObject[number],
    units: '%'
  }
}

console.log(theObject);
```

```html
<script>
const theObject = {
  "1": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 0
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 0
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 23.77
    }
  ],
  "nth": [
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    },
    {
      "date": 1638334800,
      "value": 19.71
    }
  ]
}</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need is for loop here:

```
for(let key in array){
  array[key] = {
    timeSeriesData: array[key],
    units: '%'
  }
}
```